# Is there an option for flex to match whole words only?

Tags: c, regex, flex-lexer, lexical-analysis

I'm writing a lexer and I'm using Flex to generate it based on custom rules.

I want to match identifiers of sorts that start with a letter and then can have either letters or numbers. So I wrote the following pattern for them:

```
[[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]]*
```

It works fine, the lexer that gets generated recognizes the pattern perfectly, although it doesn't only match whole words but all appearances of that pattern.

So for example it would match the input "Text" and "9Text" (discarding that initial 9).

Consider the following simple lexer that accepts IDs as described above:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>

#define LINE_END 1
#define ID       2

%}

/* Flex options: */
%option noinput
%option nounput
%option noyywrap
%option yylineno

/* Definitions: */
WHITESPACE  [ \t]
BLANK       {WHITESPACE}+
NEW_LINE    "\n"|"\r\n"
ID          [[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]_]*

%%

{NEW_LINE}        {printf("New line.\n"); return LINE_END;}
{BLANK}           {/* Blanks are skipped */}
{ID}              {printf("ID recognized: '%s'\n", yytext); return ID;}
.                 {fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Invalid input in line %d: \"%s\"\n", yylineno, yytext);}

%%

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
   while (yylex() != 0);
   return 0;
}
```

When compiled and fed the following input produces the output below:

Input:

```
Test
9Test
```

Output:

```
Test
ID recognized: 'Test'
New line.
9Test
ERROR: Invalid input in line 2: "9"
ID recognized: 'Test'
New line.
```

Is there a way to make flex match only whole words (i.e. delimited by either blanks or custom delimiters like '(' ')' for example)?

Because I could write a rule that excludes IDs that start with numbers, but what about the ones that start with symbols like "$Test" or "&Test"? I don't think I can enumerate all of the possible symbols.

Following the example above, the desired output would be:

```
Test
ID recognized: 'Test'
New line.
9Test
ERROR: Invalid input 2: "9Test"
New line.
```

Comment: Can you give some examples of 'whole words'?

Comment: @chucksys Hi, sorry for the wording of the question, it reckon it wasn't clear enough what I wanted to accomplish. I've updated the question with a _buildable_ example and a test case.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be asking two questions at once.

1. 'Whole word' isn't a recognized construct in programming languages. The lexical and grammar are already defined. Just implement them.
2. The best way to handle illegal or unexpected characters in flex is not to handle them specially at all. Return them to the parser, just as you would for a special character. Then the parser can deal with it and attempt recovery via discarding.

Place this as you final rule:

```
. return yytext[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best answer, but this works for me.

```
%x ERROR
%%

{NL} {
    printf("New line.\n");
    return LINE_END;
}

<INITIAL,ERROR>{BLANK} {
    BEGIN(INITIAL);
}

{ID} {
    printf("ID recognized: '%s'\n", yytext);
    return ID;
}
<INITIAL,ERROR>. {
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Invalid input in line %d: \"%s\"\n", yylineno, yytext);
    BEGIN(ERROR);
}

%%
```

Read [this](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Start-Conditions.html) to learn more about starting conditions.

(My attempt at explaining what I've done)
Whenever this lexer hits something unexpected, it exclusively activates 2 sets of rules. To get out of the error set of rules, the lexer has to hit a 'blank'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

Lets say you want to identify the reserved word for :

```
([\r\n\z]|" "|"")+"for"/([\r\n\z]|" ")+ {}
```

- any new line character or generally a control character `[\r\n\z]`
- or a white space `" "`
- or the beginning of the line `""`
- for at least 1 time `+`
- the word you want in quotes `"for"`
- only followed by `/`
- almost the same expression without the `""` at least 1 time -> `([\r\n\z]|" ")+`

With this code you can form your own matching pattern for whatever you need to do before and after the word.